# How to forward all traffic from second device through openVPN tunnel?

Tags: routing, openvpn, tunnel

I want to connect a new machine remotely to our company network, so it can access the active directory there.

The old machine has access to the company network through an OpenVPN tunnel.

When connecting through the tunnel, it gets a company internal IP per DHCP, Nameservers are overwritten with the internal company nameservers, and any IP ranges related to the company network are routed through the tunnel.

On the new machine, I have no account yet, so there is no way to configure it. I first need to connect it to the company network and enter my credentials.

Both machines are macOS, but I assume it‘s a general Linux question.

What do I need to set up on the old machine so that the new machine and the company network think that it is in the network and gets its own IP, etc?

I can connect both machines with an ethernet cable and the old machine has a normal wireless connection and the OpenVPN tunnel uses this wireless connection.

So the biggest question is what packets need to be routed from the ethernet connection to the tunnel and back? If you have the commands on how to set it up on a Mac, that would be awesome, but even understanding what has to happen would help a lot!

If it makes life easier, I don‘t need the OpenVPN tunnel on the first machine while the forwarding takes place. And I could switch on the „route all traffic through tunnel“ if the split configuration causes issues.

Assumption (for command examples): The ad-server has name xy.company.net and ip 1.2.3.4

Clarified in comments:
It‘s a new macbook and i need to login once to create/activate my user account. To do that, the new macbook needs access to the company AD server. Which is probably configured with a company internal name, so it needs to do the DNS requests against the company nameservers, which means it has to know them first, I assume from DHCP.

I also assume I can create fake services for all devices connected to the ethernet port of old macbook, but that sounds lile overkill.

Still believe there could be some way to share the openVPN tunnel (tun interface) of the old macbook. Basically all traffic coming from the ethernet card should be forwarded to the company network and all responses should be forwarded to the new macbook.

is this called a bridge or something else? do i use the route command or something else? i hve a basic understanding of ll the network teems, but no real wxperience. so any help is welcome!

Comment: Do you want to use "all ports" to be forwarded from company on "new machine"? Then best is something like e.g. a tun/tap device and VPN on your old machine. But if it is just about a small amount of ports to be accessible then you can use `ssh` with option `-R` and/or `-L` to create tunnels. Hint: After testing ssh tunnels in shell you should write them to `~/.ssh/config` to make more simple `ssh`calls.

Comment: i have no idea which ports it will connect too. probably it will do dhcp, then a dna call, then ad login, maybe pull some config files. best would be to route all the traffic i think

Comment: You don't need dhcp if you are just using tunnels. Let me phrase it differently: Are there custom services/servers in your company which you need to connect to? E.g. Bugtracker, Wiki and more.

Comment: not really, it‘s a new device and i need to login once to activate the account. to do that it needs access to the AD server, which is probably configured by name, so it needs to do dns requests against the company nameservers, which means it has to know them, i assume from dhcp

Comment: i could drive to the company, but that would be a longer journey and now i am set on fixing the problem remotely :)

Comment: Even UDP can be forwarded via ssh tunnels but if it is just for DNS then we can use hosts file. Please provide more details which services in company you need to access via "new machine": host/ip and port. Without details nobody could provide a solution. And be sure that there IS a solution.

Comment: are you sure? i cannot change anything on the new machine. i get a login screen and that‘s it. cannot boot into recovery mode, etc.

Comment: what would be your suggestion if the ad-server has name xy.company.net and ip 1.2.3.4?

Answer (score 1):

*Update/Note: According to Daniel's comment this solution doesn't work for him because of missing `ssh` connection to "newmachine". Nevertheless keeping it in case that someone else can use this.*

Unfortunately you can't give many details. Hence we need to do some basic steps.

You didn't specify an OS but I will use some standard or Linux commands to explain. I assume that "oldmachine" and "newmachine" are running Linux or a "compatible" OS.

> what would be your suggestion if the ad-server has name xy.company.net
> and ip 1.2.3.4?

First be sure that **on "newmachine" nothing is running on tcp port 80 or 443** (should work on Linux and BSD):

```
newmachine$ netstat -lnt|grep ^tcp|awk '{print$4}' |sed 's,.*[.:],,'|sort -u|egrep '^80$|^443$'
newmachine$
```

If there is no `80` or `443` written then you are fine. Otherwise you need to terminate the process running on that port(s).

Then on "newmachine" start a shell session, **do an `ssh` connection to "oldmachine"** and keep it open:

```
newmachine# ssh -L 80:1.2.3.4:80 -L 443:1.2.3.4:443 youraccount@oldmachine
oldmachine$
```

The two `-L` options create two `ssh` tunnels.

`-L 80:1.2.3.4:80` means:

- `L` = **L**ocal port is listening. Means that on "newmachine" a listening port will be opened, the "start of the tunnel"
- `80` this is the tcp port listening on "newmachine"
- `1.2.3.4` the IP# of the tunnel endpoint (as reached from "oldmachine")
- `80` the tcp port at the tunnel endpoint

If you didn't get any error messages then your tunnels are up and you can connect from "newmachine" to `xy.company.net`.

But for browser access (virtual hosts in use?) we also need to **set up the DNS resolution**. Simply add an entry to `/etc/hosts`:

```
newmachine# echo "127.0.0.1 xy.company.net" >>/etc/hosts
newmachine#
```

Why `127.0.0.1`?

Well, first of all you can't reach `xy.company.net` directly from "newmachine" because it is not connected to company's VPN - only "oldmachine" is. Next thing is that your access is tunnelled from "newmachine" via `ssh` login on "oldmachine" through its VPN to `xy.company.net`. That means your tunnel startpoint is "newmachine" itself - hence `127.0.0.1`!

Now you should be able to access `xy.company.net` from within your web browser on "newmachine" with these URLs:

- http://xy.company.net
- https://xy.company.net

How does it work? For http:

1. Browser gets DNS resolution of 127.0.0.1 for xy.company.net
2. It connects to 127.0.0.1 port 80.
3. At this port your tunnel starts. The traffic is routed via your open `ssh` connection to "oldmachine" and from there to `1.2.3.4:80`.
4. Connection from "oldmachine" to 1.2.3.4 is going to company's VPN and then finally to 1.2.3.4 in your company.

Maybe this does not perfectly match your issue but based on this you maybe can provide more technical details. And with some iterations we could finally find the perfect answer for you.

*Note: As opposite to `-L` there's also a `-R` which opens a port on the **R**emote side and tunnel back.*

*Note2: `$` means shell prompt, `#` means root shell prompt*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the long explanation. If I had access to the new machine, it probably would work. unfortunatelly I only get the login screen and am supposed to enter my credentials. will give you an upvote for the effort, but still waiting for a solution that only needs to modify routes (or whatever) on the old machine.

Comment: OK, that means that "oldmachine" is the only one under your control? Do you have root access? Besides the "login screen" on "newmachine": Did you even try to login by `ssh` to "newmachine"? We can set up routes, dhcpd and/or VPN to get "newmachine" connected to company's VPN via "oldmachine" but we need root permissions (at least on "oldmachine") to do that.

Comment: yes, in the good old days everyone got root permissions, so we can modify whatever we want on oldmachine.

Comment: In this case you can setup a DHCP server, DNS server (cache) and additional VPN on oldmachine, connect newmachine to it and it should work. The only additional requirement is that your company's VPN does not route ALL traffic through the VPN. In this case newmachine can't simply connect and you'll have also to modify the routes set by company's VPN to allow access to your LAN.